# Get x value of 2.9

Tags: php, math

Total = 2.9
Percentage = 20%

Find the X number below 2.9

`X + (X * 20%) = 2.9`

So we need to get number below 2.9 which one we include 20% to reach 2.9

Comment: This looks more like  a math question to me. Not coding question.

Comment: Do you think you can clarify this question a little please?

Comment: We need to find number below 2.9

Which number is < 2.9

Example we found 1.5 
So 1.5 is below 2.9 

1.5 + 20% of 1.5 = 2.9

Comment: 1.5 is not an accurate number it's just for example. We need to get that with formula

Comment: What's your question about this? How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `2.9 / 1.20 = X`.
This will give you the number X that when you add 20% of that number will give you 2.9.

So in php:

```php
$total = 2.9;
$percentage = 20;
$x = $total / (1 + $percentage / 100);
```

Comment: How you got 1.20

Comment: See my updatet answer with php code.